# How to remove highlight on tap of Button with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have a button and label for this simple app. When I tap the button, it highlights my button (you can see in the attached image), so how can I disable that? What am I missing?

**Code:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var displayLabel = 0
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geo in
            ZStack{
                Button(action: {
                    displayLabel += 1
                }, label: {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                }).buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                
                Text("\(displayLabel)")
                    .font(Font.system(size:75, design: .rounded))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a custom `ButtonStyle` with no highlighting:

```
struct StaticButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
    }
}
```

```
Button(action: {
    displayLabel += 1
}) {
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
}
.buttonStyle(StaticButtonStyle())
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply the style `.plain` to your button to avoid overlay color.

```
// Before
Button(...)
```

[image: with button styling]

```
// After
Button(...)
.buttonStyle(.plain) // Remove the overlay color (blue) for images inside Button
```

- `.plain` button style, that doesn’t style or decorate its content while idle, but may apply a visual effect to indicate the pressed, focused, or enabled state of the button.

[image: without button styling]

Another solution is to custom the style with `ButtonStyle`

like: `struct MyButtonStyle:ButtonStyle { }`